# How to show the derivative of $g(t) = f(x+t(y-x))$ is $g'(t)=\langle \nabla f(x+t(y-x)),y-x \rangle$?

Tags: derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and assume $f$ is continuously differentiable. Show that the derivative of $g(t) = f(x+t(y-x))$ where $t \in [0,1]$ is $g'(t)=\langle \nabla f(x+t(y-x)),y-x \rangle$.

I tried the following:

$$
g'(t) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+(t+h)(y-x))-f(x+t(y-x))}{h}
$$

Rearrange

$$
g'(t) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+t(y-x) + h(y-x))-f(x+t(y-x))}{h}
$$

Do not know how to proceed.
Also, is there any way to implicitly prove chain rule here?

Comment: have you seen the multivariate chain rule? Or, do you know what a directional derivative is?

Comment: @Calvin Khor: I am but I am not sure how to apply them on the last limit. I appropriate if you apply them to conclude the proof.

Comment: If you want to use the limit definition, then there is no chain rule to help you. Instead use $h(a+s) - h(a) = \nabla h \cdot s + o(s)$

Comment: @ Calvin Khor: Great! thank you for the insight.